# Android remove Fastforward and rewind buttons from mediaplayer

Tags: android, mediacontroller

I would Like to remove the fastforward and rewind buttons from mediacontroller in Android. Can anyone help me with this? I want to do it inside my main activity.

Answer (score 28):

When creating a MediaController, make sure to set the boolean to **false** in the constructor:

```
MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this, false);
```

From the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/MediaController.html):

> The "rewind" and "fastforward" buttons are shown unless requested otherwise by using the MediaController(Context, boolean) constructor with the boolean set to false

Comment: I guess, this should be accepted answer for the question above as this removes the rewind and forward button from the videoView

Comment: I also want to remove the play icon and only want to show the seek-bar, how can i achieve this?

Comment: @hasnain_ahmad how to remove play pause also?

Comment: @RuchaBhattJoshi that's outside of this question's concerns. but a quick google search leads me to this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/40364545/2475185. Hopefully it still works

Comment: @Yasha yeah i guess so, anyways thank you so much :)

Answer (score 6):

If you're trying to remove the buttons from a MediaPlayer than is not part of your app, this is impossible. You cannot mess with other apps' code. Some of them may allow you to pass this as an intent extra while launching them, but the majority probably won't.

If it is part of your app, just comment out the code related to the buttons.

EDIT: From the [MediaController](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/MediaController.html) documentation:

- The "rewind" and "fastforward" buttons are shown unless requested
  otherwise by using the MediaController(Context, boolean) constructor
  with the boolean set to false

So all you need to do is pass false in the constructor.

Comment: (http://www.devdaily.com/java/jwarehouse/android/core/java/android/widget/MediaController.java.shtml).They are saying that you can by using the MediaController(Context, boolean) constructor
with the boolean set to false.

Comment: Well, you have access to the source. Not sure why you'd want to remove a feature, but you can comment the code for those buttons out.

Comment: I havent made any buttons. I am using the standard mediacontroller that has the buttons within itself.  `     mVideoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.surface_view); 
      MediaController mc = new MediaController(this); 
      mVideoView.setMediaController(mc); `

Comment: What is the code for that so i should use it in my main activity.