# Remove Backward & Forward Button From Media Controller

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I Use MediaController to play my audio. But, I want to remove Backward & Forward Button from my MediaController. Please, help me. (PS. A Code is be useful) How can I edit it.

```
public class Main extends Activity implements MediaPlayerControl {
    private static final String PLAY_AUDIO = "PLAY_AUDIO";  
    private MediaController mMediaController
    private MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;
    private Handler mHandler = new Handler();

    static Context context;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        context = this;


        mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mMediaController = new MediaController(this);

        mMediaController.setMediaPlayer(Main.this);
        mMediaController.setAnchorView(findViewById(R.id.audioView));
        mMediaController.setPrevNextListeners(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //next button clicked
            }       
        }, new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //previous button clicked
            }
        });

        try { 
            mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(
                this,
                Uri.parse("android.resource://com.app.audioplayer/raw/allforyou")
            );
            mMediaPlayer.prepare();         
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(PLAY_AUDIO, "Could not open file " + "  " + " for playback.", e);         
        }

        mMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        mMediaController.show(0);
                        mMediaPlayer.start();
                    }
                });
            } 
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: Sorry I'm rookie Programmer. T_T

Comment: <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11282895/android-remove-fastforward-and-rewind-buttons-from-mediaplayer> check this if it helps in anyways...

Comment: Oh ! It's not work. I want to use MediaController.

Comment: Wait for Someboby again. Thank for help.

Comment: MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this, false);

Answer (score 3):

Simplest solution ...

```
MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this, false);
```

Courtesy : @Meow meo (in comments of original question)

Comment: if I just want to disable forward ?