# Hide play pause button of media controller in android

Tags: android, android-videoview

I have video View in my activity also having MediaController but I want to hide the play pause button from media controller.

Here is my code:

```
MediaController mediaController =  new MediaController(this,false);
videoHolder.setMediaController(mediaController);
mediaController.setAnchorView(videoHolder);
```

Please suggest me solutions.

Comment: did you try the `visibility` function?

Comment: On which component should I use it?

Comment: you have buttons in your layout, dont you?

Comment: I want to hide button of media controller

Comment: aaaah, sry.. i went wrong ^^ my head where anywhere else, sry... have you tried the developer-site?http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/MediaController.html

Comment: want to have seek bar but dont want any other things from media controller

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/MediaController.html

Comment: @AnkitHTech did you find the solution?

Answer (score 4):

I have managed to achieve the same. By default Media Controller doesn't expose any method to hide the play/pause control. Hence we have to loop through the child views of Media Controller, get the desired view and do whatever you want to do with that view.

In my case, I did in following way ->

```
videoPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
              LinearLayout viewGroupLevel1 = (LinearLayout)  media_Controller.getChildAt(0);
            LinearLayout viewGroupLevel2 = (LinearLayout) viewGroupLevel1.getChildAt(0);
            View view = viewGroupLevel2.getChildAt(2);
            view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            videoPlayer.start();
        }
    }); `
```

To explain my code, Basically Media Controller is a subclass of FrameLayout and it has one LinearLayout as a child viewgroup (viewGroupLevel1) at position 0, again viewGroupLevel1 contains two children view groups, out of which get the viewgroup (viewGroupLevel2) from viewGroupLevel1 at position 0. Now in viewGroupLevel2 get the view of position 2 which is actually an imagebutton (Play/Pause button). Now you can easily hide it. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

You can see
http://www.phonesdevelopers.com/1765331/

```
    MediaController mc = new MediaController(this);  
    mc.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);  
    videoView.setMediaController(mc);
```

it's worked

Comment: It hide all the `MediaController` view.

Comment: It's worked but thin black border line of MediaController view will be displayed, So this solution not worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try it ( not sure)

Use OnPreparedListener and in the callback onPrepared do your hide inderectly, like:

```
@Override
public void onPrepared (MediaPlayer mp) 
{
    int childs = mediaController.getChildCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < childs; i++)
    {
        View child = mediaController.getChildAt (i);
        child.setVisibility (View.GONE);
    }
}
```